# letters are not counted using OR in javascript. any reason?

Tags: javascript, string, conditional-statements

Learning javascript I've written this :

```
function compterNbVoyelles() {
    var nombreDeVoyelles = 0;
    var mot = "Anaconda";
    for (var i = 0; i < mot.length; i++) {
        var lettre = mot[i].toLowerCase();
        if (lettre === ('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y')) {
            nombreDeVoyelles++;
        }
    }
    return nombreDeVoyelles;
}

console.log(mot + " has " + compterNbVoyelles(mot) + " vowels and " + (mot.length - compterNbVoyelles()) + " consonants");
```

It prints:

> Anaconda has 3 vowels and 5 consonants... (there are 4 vowels in fact).

now this :

```
function compterNbVoyelles(mot) {
    var nombreDeVoyelles = 0;
    var mot = "Anaconda";

    for (var i = 0; i < mot.length; i++) {
        var lettre = mot[i].toLowerCase();
        if ((lettre === 'a') || (lettre === 'e') || (lettre === 'i') ||
            (lettre === 'o') || (lettre === 'u') || (lettre === 'y')) {
            nombreDeVoyelles++;
        }
    }
    return nombreDeVoyelles;
}
```

It prints :

> Anaconda has 4 vowels and 4 consonants

Perfect! I don't get what is my mistake, and I assume the computer doesn't make any ;)

Comment: try some random order like `(lettre === ('e'|| 'a' || 'o' || 'i' || 'u' || 'y'))` .. you will get the script play maybe

Comment: If you have multiple conditions that share a common value, you should have each one separate repeating that common value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays in your if condition. First you need to understand how short circuit operations in javascript.

While evaluating a condition, javascript is going to perform the least possible amount of work to evaluate a boolean answer.

---

In the case of || (which is a logical or) if you do:

```
if (condition1 || condition2 || condition3) {
    // do something
}
```

If condition1 is true then it's only going to evaluate condition1, it will never run through condition2 and condition3 because no matter if they are true of not, the result is going to be true.

If condition2 is false, then it's going to continue evaluating condition2 and stop at the first true condition.

---

In the case of && (which is a logical and) if you do:

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) {
    // do something
}
```

Here the short circuit works differently, it's going to stop evaluating as soon as it meets a false value. Because no matter what the result is going to be false.

---

Faulty values in Javascript are

- false
- 0
- "" (empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN (the result of 1/0 for example)

---

Back to your example:

```
'a'|| 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y'
```

'a' ALWAYS evaluates to true therefore this entire condition will return you the first truthy value: 'a'

your condition then simplifies to

```
if (letters === 'a')
```

How many 'a' do you have in anaconda ? 3 therefore that's why you obtain 3 vowels.

---

Your second way to build the condition is the correct one. If you want to search for an element in an array you can use [Array.indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

Answer (score 1):

When you do `lettre === ('a'|| 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y')` it evaluates what's in the brackets first before comparing it with `lettre`.

Evaluating what's in the brackets will result in just `'a'` as that counts as a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), so in the end that line effectively becomes `lettre === 'a'`

```js
console.log(('a'|| 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

whereas in the second (working example) your saying does `lettre === 'a'` or `lettre === 'e'` and so on, rather than just comparing it with one value

Comment: got it, thank you!! took me a minute to understand that it took only "a" in count... and there are 3 "a" in anaconda... a is firts in my OR conditions.

Comment: @Gab Glad you got it, it was kinda hard to explain in words.

Answer (score 0):

`lettre === ('a'|| 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y')` is actually equivalent to `lettre === ('a')`. Try putting `x = ('a'|| 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y')` and see the output. So your answer was just counting a.

Another option is to do something like `(['a','e','i','o','u','y']).includes(lettre);`